# JVM Monitoring jar execution

Tags: jar, jvm, jconsole

I want to check the memory usage of a JAR that does some calculations. For this I want to use JVM monitor. When starting JVM monitor, I need to pick the JVM that is running my jar. But the problem is that my JAR executes so fast (<1sec) that it never shows up in the list..

Is there any way I can start the JVM without executing the JAR immediatly?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. What's the point of JVM Monitor if I have to add a wait at the beginning of my program **and** at the end of my program? JVM Monitor should start monitoring automatically, and it should save every instance of every program started.

Answer (score 0):

JConsole finds running applications at the time when JConsole starts . Then only the currently running applications port and host will be displayed in the list. But for such very short running applications to be shown in the list adding a wait at the end of program execution is the only choice you can do .

Also whatever the memory stats Jconsole will display will include Jconsole's memory footprint as well. So the better choice for monitoring is jvisualvm which can show memory , threads and gc statistics as well .

Alternatevely if you want to check the code cache or compilation statistics you can use -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCodeCache